# Don't know how to explain, issue requires resolving

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

```
bot.on('message', function(message) {
if(!message.content.includes("ew")) {
      if(!message.author.bot) {
          message.delete();
      }
  }
});
```

I have a problem with this specific line in my code. I want this to strictly only allow "ew" and only "ew" with no additional words in front or back. The issue is that it allows any words to be in front or at the back of it, as long as it contains "ew" somewhere in it.

How could I resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: `if (message.content == "ew")...` ?

Comment: Edited the post with the full code so that it is more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've said in my comment, you can just check the whole `message.content` against any string you wish to test and accept/reject all the others:

```
bot.on('message', function(message) {
    if(message.content !== "ew") {
          if(!message.author.bot) {
              message.delete();
          }
    }
});
```

This will issue a delete command to all (non-bot) messages that are not exactly `ew` and only `ew`.